# Multiplying polynomials in python

Tags: python

I did the adding and the subtracting but I am having a really hard time multiplying to polynomials in python.

For example, if I have:

```
2X^2 + 5X + 1 [1,5,2]
```

and...

```
3X^3 + 4X^2 + X + 6 [6,1,4,3]
```

We get:

```
6X^5 + 23X^4 + 25X^3 + 21X^2 + 31X + 6 [6,31,21,25,23,6]
```

I am desperate. I have been working at it for days. Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Might be a dumb question since I'm not a huge Python user, but have you looked at this library: http://numpy.scipy.org/

Comment: Are you having trouble with python, or with the algorithm?

Comment: Numpy's got the routines, but this almost certainly a homework problem, so the OP will need his own code to work.

Comment: @Joel.I am having trouble with the algorithm

Comment: Now Python has this module:     https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/routines.polynomials.polynomial.html

Answer (score 22):

```
s1 = [1,5,2]
s2 = [6,1,4,3]
res = [0]*(len(s1)+len(s2)-1)
for o1,i1 in enumerate(s1):
    for o2,i2 in enumerate(s2):
        res[o1+o2] += i1*i2
```

**Edit:** In honor of @katrielalex:

```
import collections
import itertools

class Polynomial(object):
    def __init__(self, *args):
        """
        Create a polynomial in one of three ways:

        p = Polynomial(poly)           # copy constructor
        p = Polynomial([1,2,3 ...])    # from sequence
        p = Polynomial(1, 2, 3 ...)    # from scalars
        """
        super(Polynomial,self).__init__()
        if len(args)==1:
            val = args[0]
            if isinstance(val, Polynomial):                # copy constructor
                self.coeffs = val.coeffs[:]
            elif isinstance(val, collections.Iterable):    # from sequence
                self.coeffs = list(val)
            else:                                          # from single scalar
                self.coeffs = [val+0]
        else:                                              # multiple scalars
            self.coeffs = [i+0 for i in args]
        self.trim()

    def __add__(self, val):
        "Return self+val"
        if isinstance(val, Polynomial):                    # add Polynomial
            res = [a+b for a,b in itertools.izip_longest(self.coeffs, val.coeffs, fillvalue=0)]
        else:                                              # add scalar
            if self.coeffs:
                res = self.coeffs[:]
                res[0] += val
            else:
                res = val
        return self.__class__(res)

    def __call__(self, val):
        "Evaluate at X==val"
        res = 0
        pwr = 1
        for co in self.coeffs:
            res += co*pwr
            pwr *= val
        return res

    def __eq__(self, val):
        "Test self==val"
        if isinstance(val, Polynomial):
            return self.coeffs == val.coeffs
        else:
            return len(self.coeffs)==1 and self.coeffs[0]==val

    def __mul__(self, val):
        "Return self*val"
        if isinstance(val, Polynomial):
            _s = self.coeffs
            _v = val.coeffs
            res = [0]*(len(_s)+len(_v)-1)
            for selfpow,selfco in enumerate(_s):
                for valpow,valco in enumerate(_v):
                    res[selfpow+valpow] += selfco*valco
        else:
            res = [co*val for co in self.coeffs]
        return self.__class__(res)

    def __neg__(self):
        "Return -self"
        return self.__class__([-co for co in self.coeffs])

    def __pow__(self, y, z=None):
        raise NotImplemented()

    def _radd__(self, val):
        "Return val+self"
        return self+val

    def __repr__(self):
        return "{0}({1})".format(self.__class__.__name__, self.coeffs)

    def __rmul__(self, val):
        "Return val*self"
        return self*val

    def __rsub__(self, val):
        "Return val-self"
        return -self + val

    def __str__(self):
        "Return string formatted as aX^3 + bX^2 + c^X + d"
        res = []
        for po,co in enumerate(self.coeffs):
            if co:
                if po==0:
                    po = ''
                elif po==1:
                    po = 'X'
                else:
                    po = 'X^'+str(po)
                res.append(str(co)+po)
        if res:
            res.reverse()
            return ' + '.join(res)
        else:
            return "0"

    def __sub__(self, val):
        "Return self-val"
        return self.__add__(-val)

    def trim(self):
        "Remove trailing 0-coefficients"
        _co = self.coeffs
        if _co:
            offs = len(_co)-1
            if _co[offs]==0:
                offs -= 1
                while offs >= 0 and _co[offs]==0:
                    offs -= 1
                del _co[offs+1:]
```

Comment: I think this would look a lot neater with non-numerical variable names or even in pseudocode; just my two cents.

Comment: @katrielalex: hope that's an improvement ;-)

Comment: Why do you have that "super(Polynomial,self).__init__()"? I've only seen that in the context of inheriting classes.

Comment: @riri: yes; Polynomial inherits from object. It takes care of odd problems such as diamond inheritance (D inherits from B and C which each inherit from A; who initializes A?). It's basically just insurance that the class behaves properly for people creating new classes based on it.

Comment: +1 for the insane effort and how thoroughly you solved the problem, despite the fact that you might be doing someone's homework.

Comment: @HughBothwell , you forgot underscore (you have _radd__ instead of __ radd __)

Answer (score 10):

```
In [1]: from numpy import convolve

In [2]: convolve([1,5,2],[6,1,4,3])
Out[2]: array([ 6, 31, 21, 25, 23,  6])
```

Answer (score 3):

If this is not an academic exercise to learn how to do it, probably everything you need is already implemented in `numpy`:

```
In [22]: import numpy as np

In [23]: p1 = np.poly1d([1,5,2])

In [24]: p2 = np.poly1d([6,1,4,3])

In [25]: p1*p2
Out[25]: poly1d([ 6, 31, 21, 25, 23,  6])
```

You can also add, subtract, calculate derivatives, etc. But if you need even more functions on polynomials, then use [`np.polynomial`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.0/reference/routines.polynomials.html) module. In fact `numpy.polynomial` is recommended for new code. The previous lines would then become:

```
In [28]: from numpy.polynomial import Polynomial as P

In [29]: p1 = P([1,5,2])

In [30]:  p2 = P([6,1,4,3])

In [31]: p1*p2
Out[31]: Polynomial([  6.,  31.,  21.,  25.,  23.,   6.], [-1.,  1.], [-1.,  1.])
```

The last two parts are the window and the domain. See the documentation for details.

Answer (score 1):

```
q = [6,1,4,3]
p = [1,5,2]
qa = zip(q, [3,2,1,0])
pa = zip(p, [2,1,0])
res = {}
for a in qa:
for b in pa:
    if a[1] + b[1] in res:
        res[a[1] + b[1]] += a[0]*b[0]
    else:
        res[a[1] + b[1]] = a[0]*b[0]
print res
```

Of course, you would need to add a little bit more to make it work for general polynomials. You could also make it faster with some of the things they use for FFTs (I think).

Comment: you start with polynomials represented by lists and end with a polynomial represented by a a dictionary. That is not a nice behaviour of your program

Answer (score 1):

```
s1 = [1,5,2]
s2 = [6,1,4,3]
mlist = [ [0]*o2+[i1*i2 for i1 in s1]+[0]*(len(s1)-o2) for o2,i2 in enumerate(s2)]
length = len(s1)+len(s2)-1
res = [ sum(row[i] for row in mlist) for i in range(length)]
```

==

or in one huge comprehension:

```
res = [ sum( row[i] 
             for row
             in [ [0]*o2
                   +[i1*i2 for i1 in s1]
                   +[0]*(len(s1)-o2)
                  for o2,i2
                  in enumerate(s2)
                ]
             )
        for i
        in range( len(s1)+len(s2)-1 )
      ]
```

Comment: I am trying to do this my way because I can not use the enumerate built in function and it prints the right length for the list but not the right numbers. :(

Comment: You haven't showed us your way. Please post your code (edit your question) so others can help you improve it. My solution is awkard, unreadable and should be deleted anyway...

Comment: on "Python 3.3.0 (v3.3.0:bd8afb90ebf2, Sep 29 2012, 10:55:48) [MSC v.1600 32 bit (Intel)] on win32", with 
s1=[1,5] and s2=[6,1,4,3] I get an IndexError: list index out of range

Answer (score 1):

The following comprehension implements polynomial multiplication using the [usual definition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polynomial_ring#Definition)  by adding dummy terms with 0 coefficients to the factor polynomials `p`and `q`:

```
(p[0]+p[1]*X+p[2]*X^2+...)*(q[0]+q[1]*X+q[2]*X^2+...)=
(p[0]*q[0])+(p[0]*q[1]+p[1]*q[0])X+(p[0]*q[2]+p[1]*q[1]+p[2]*q[0])X^2+...
```

So `(p+[0]*(len(q)-1))` extends the list `p` by `len(q)-1` zeroes to a list of lenght `len(p)+len(q)-1`

```
[sum([ (p+[0]*(len(q)-1))[i]*(q+[0]*(len(p)-1))[k-i]
   for i in range(1+k)
   ]
 ) for k in range(len(p)+len(q)-1)]
```

The following comprehension avoids adding dummy 0-coefficient terms to the polynomials `p` and `q` by choosing a proper start and end for the range of the indices

```
[sum([ p[i]*q[k-i]
   for i in range(
       max([0,k-len(q)+1]),
       1+min([k,len(p)-1])
       )
   ]
 ) for k in range(len(p)+len(q)-1)]
```

For

```
p=[6,1,4,3]
q=[1,5,2]
```

the result is

```
[6, 31, 21, 25, 23, 6]
```

Answer (score 0):

If all you need is `(x+a)*(x+b)*(x+c)...` then this does the trick:

```
from itertools import combinations
from operator import mul

def poly(*args):
    return [sum([reduce(mul,c,1) for c in combinations(args,i)]) 
                                 for i in range(len(args)+1)]
```

e.g. `(x+1)*(x+2)` is computed by `poly(1, 2)` which produces `[1, 3, 4]` which corresponds to `1*x^2 + 3*x + 4`